# rsync not deleting folders

Tags: rsync

I back up my wifes' stuff to a raspberry pi. She has sorted out some stuff, moving files and folders, but rsync isnt reproducing the changes. Can anyone tell me why ?

I mount the (windows) share

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.96/Users/PC /mnt/wife-PC -o username=PC,password=xxxx,ro,uid=pi,gid=pi
```

then rsync it

```
rsync -vv -rtdizb --no-owner --no-perms --no-group  --exclude *ini --exclude *Trash* --progress --log-file=/tmp/rsynclog --backup-dir=/mnt/seagate/deletedfiles/wife-PC/backup-2020-09-07 --delete /mnt/wife-PC/Documents   /mnt/seagate/wife-PC
```

The new changed source

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/wife-PC/Documents...Family/wife/ALL\ PHOTOS/ | grep '\bF\w*' | grep -v Feb 
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi      0 Apr 18  2018 Farm & Garden
rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 1108 Sep  7 16:04 Family Photos - Shortcut.lnk
```

the target.Id expected it to move 'From dropbox' and 'From phone' and contents , but it hasnt

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/seagate/wife-PC/....wife/ALL\ PHOTOS/ |grep '\bF\w*' | grep -v Feb 

drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      4096 Apr 18  2018  Farm & Garden
rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      1108 Sep  7 16:04 Family Photos - Shortcut.lnk
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi      4096 Jun  7  2017 Flood 
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 32768 Sep  7 19:41 From dropbox 21Dec18 
drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 0    Aug 26 18:15 From Phone 26Aug20 pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

it has put the old  .lnk  in the deleted files folder

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /mnt/seagate/deletedfiles/wife-PC/backup-2020-09-07/Documents/.....y/wife/ALL\ PHOTOS/ total 4
rwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 887 Mar  4  2013 Family Photos - Shortcut.lnk pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: You're running with -vv.  Do these folders appear in the output?

Comment: the log file : 

    $ cat /tmp/rsynclog | grep dropbox
2020/09/07 19:53:02 [19105] directory has vanished: "/mnt/wife-PC/Documents/fam...../ALL PHOTOS/From dropbox 21Dec18"

Comment: the log file : 


ran out of time !

2020/09/07 19:53:11 [19105] .d..t...... Documents/fam....ALL PHOTOS/From dropbox 21Dec18/

Comment: "Directory has vanished" sounds like the SMB mount has gone away.  May not be a rsync problem, but a network or SMB issue.  I'd probably look through the log and find the last place progress was made.  See if there's anything odd about that point.

Answer (score 1):

the -r and the -d options dont go together.  ( not sure how they both got there !)

rsync -vv -rtib  works as expected

Comment: Interesting.  I did notice that originally, but the documentation suggests that -r overrides -d.  "If you specify both --dirs and --recursive, --recursive takes precedence."  Your experience suggests that statement from the manual is incomplete.

Comment: Documentation says, "_If you specify both --dirs and --recursive, --recursive takes precedence_", so your `rsync -vv -rtib` is the same as `rsync -vv -rtdib`

Comment: The `-z` is pointless on a local-filesystem to local-filesystem copy. You'd be far better off not mounting the Pi with SMB but instead using rsync to copy over ssh to the Pi. At the moment your `rsync` is basically `cp -a`, so any change to a file causes the entire file to be recopied.